# Accessibility services gets disabled automatically

Tags: accessibility

I have a Gionee p3s.  I was trying to use tasker when i observed that the tasker accessibility service gets disabled automatically after a few minutes. Not only with tasker, all apps requiring accessibility services are having the same problem.
My android version is 5.1. It will be helpful if some one can help me with this problem. :-)

Comment: Related: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/197917/347677

Comment: This problem still happens, inconsistently, in Android 11, six years later.

Answer (score 5):

I was facing the same issue on my Lenovo vibe k5. I did the followings to solve the issue.

1. Enable accessibility for the concerned app in the Settings.
2. In power saving option (in most cases it is inside the "Battery" option) select the concerned app not to be optimized.
3. Select the app as device administrator (this setting may be found inside "Security" option).
4. If possible lock the app in Task Manager so that it will not be killed when you kill all the tasks(apps). In "mi" phones you need to slide the app downward to lock it in Task Manager. I don't know how to do it in Gionee p3s. In my device this option is not available so I never kill the concerned app in the Task Manager( Or if I kill the app I re-enable the accessibility, then it remains enabled until I kill that app again).

After doing these the Accessibility option remained enabled even after restarting the phone.
This may not be the exact solution you asking for, but this is all I found after hours of searching.

Comment: I have done all these steps and still Tasker sometimes fails due to Accessibility access. It is difficult to find a way to generate this problem reproducibly, or to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

Disabling battery optimisation was not enough for me, I had to disabled battery saver completely as every time it kicked in all of my accessibility services were disabled.

Also the offending service for me was Last Pass but the principle is the same.

Comment: I can't find an option to turn off battery saver, only an option to turn it ON.

Comment: you just need to make sure it isn't set to kick in automatically at 15% or whatever

Comment: I have no idea what that means. Beginners need specific instructions.

Comment: no problem, didn't realise you were a beginner! Does battery saver turn on automatically for you once your battery level dips below a certain percentage?

Comment: I don't know how to find out. But I don't usually let the battery fall below 50%. The accessibility access stops when the device is left to charge, probably because the data of all apps is automatically backed up to Google One. I did find a way to change the battery indicator from white to orange, but I don't know what that means. The device's manual is not detailed, and I cannot find detailed instructions for use either for Android 11 or TCL A3 on the Web.

Comment: I think that sounds like a different issue I'm afraid, I'm not sure what to suggest. This issue presents when the battery drops to a certain level rather than being charged. Unless when you're turning it orange you're manually turning batter saver on in which case that's why it's happening. Battery saver mode does turn it orange

Answer (score 0):

Hii I use the same p3s and I have found better solution.

- go to advanced settings then accessibility
  make the services on then

*go to power management

in that go to power manager

- take power saving mode and click on info button (right side)
- unright (deactivate open the green background) 
  don't forget to save.

  you are done

Comment: On my device (TCL A3/Tracfone/Android 11) there is no Settings > power manager. When I use Settings > search for "power saving" or "power manager" there is no result.

Answer (score 0):

In my cade, oppo f1s, i found out one solution
First of all your device should be rooted, the best 
way to do that is through resetting firmware to factory or updating to newer oppo system image, then installing custom recovery BIOS or whatever it's name is, then 
then rooting under Recovery mode using Magisc... 
All this is described in some xda-developers forum topic.
But that is not our issue for now,
To prevent accessibility permission to be revoked 
from our service or app, we have to go developper, 
by browsing SETTINGS >> DEVICE INFO , then clicking about 8 times or more on BUIL NUMBER... now that we 
have become DEVELOPPER for good, we go back and then 
we navigate towards SETTINGS >> ADVANCED SETTINGS >> DEVELOPPER SETTINGS... then enable DEVELOPPER OPTIONS, open section RUNNING SERVICES, browse for application named SECURITY CENTER, inside whitch we can see 4 running services, then STOP service named 
CONTROL_VERIFY_SERVICE (of course on your own risk) 
, that is it, now just go to SETTINGS >> ADVACED SETTINGS >> ACCESSIBILITY and enable accessibikity for your application and enjoy it.....

Comment: I installed a Service manager and it could not find a service named security center in Android 11.