# Accessibility turned back off - how to keep it on?

Tags: battery-life, huawei, accessibility, automate

I'm using the app 'Automate', in order for it to work I have to turn it on in Settings/Accessibility:
[image: accessibility]
But after a short time I doesn't work anymore and it's back on 'off' again. 
I think it may have something to do with my battery saving mode because I've seen it in a different question but no idea how to fix it because my gui doesn't have the same properties as suggested in an answer I've seen somewhere else. [image: Battery saving]
I'm using an Honor 9 phone from Huawei, my software versions:
[image: software]
So my question is: **How can I prevent my phone from changing the app's accessibility setting without giving up on the battery saving feature (if that is the reason for it)?**

Comment: Ensure Automate is enabled as a "Protected App".

Comment: @ballzak Where do I enable that?

Comment: Dunno, it's a non-standard Huawei feature.

Comment: Related: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/137195/347677

Answer (score 1):

This probably is the battery saving mode (Android 7) as you suggest.

On my Samsung you can mark Automate (or any other app) as an app not to be checked for battery drain.

- From *Settings*, select *Device maintenance*.
- Select *Battery* at    the bottom left of the screen.
- At the bottom    of the next screen is    a list of apps that are
  currently considered    by Android as using    power.  Automate is
  probably on that list.
- Below the list is a button "*Unmonitored Apps*", select this.
- Select *Add apps* and add Automate to those apps that are no longer
  checked and put to sleep by the OS.

The exact method may be slightly different on your phone but the principle should be the same.

Comment: The first point 'Device Maintenance' is already not there on my phone :(