# Accessibility for Gesture Controls gets disabled at least daily

Tags: accessibility

I read through and tested all the solutions here but to no avail : [Accessibility services gets disabled automatically](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/137195/accessibility-services-gets-disabled-automatically)

On Xiaomi 12S Ultra with latest MIUI. disabled all optimizations, battery saver etc but it somehow turns off my accessibility without me doing it (or it will just state - not working. Tap for info.) and there's no further info from the system.

What else can I do? It's not app specific as it also happens on FNG and Vivid Navigation gestures.